# WordPressd suddenly doesn't load

Tags: wordpress

2 days ago my blog stopped working suddenly. When I went to load my page It just showed me a blank page, you can check it by this address: http://blog.df-gamez.com.

I did nothing to it, there is nothing suspicious about it but a few days earlier we had a spam sender on our blog.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-uploading WP files (same version) and theme files.

Comment: I tried it but, nothing happened. I think it's something kinda related to WordPress itself.